# Docker - ASP.NET Core 2.0 with Angular 4 template

Tags: angular, docker

I created a basic app in ASP.NET Core 2.0 with Angular template, added Docker support, built it, ran it but when I navigate in the browser to the container IP, I just get the Error page in my app. A basic web app with no Angular template works just fine with the same Docker file, so I assume this is related to Angular routing. Has this occurred to anyone else?

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "appweb.dll"]
```

Comment: Please read the *"Help others reproduce the problem"* section of [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Who knows whether it's the same as anyone else's problem? You haven't provided any meaningful detail about your code, config, or the exact error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Angular. The error you are experiencing is due to the fact that the aspnetcore image used for your built application does not include node, which is a dependency for the default SPA template. In order to get your application to run, you will have to create an image from the aspnetcore image that includes node. Try taking a look at this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples/issues/61) for more information.